# order time difference from magento 1 to magento 2 after migration

Tags: magento2.3.0, data-migration, timezone, magento1.9.3.1

I have migrated Magento 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.3.0

I have setup timezone India Standard Time(Asia/Kolkata).

After migration created_time have **differences of 5:30 hours**. How can I fix the issue?

For example:

```
In Magento 1.9 order purchased on: Jun 18, 2019 06:46:43 AM

But In Magento 2.3.0 order purchased_date: Jun 18, 2019 12:16:43 PM
```

Comment: Magento 1.9.3.1 - which timezone have ?

Comment: India Standard Time

Answer (score 1):

Please check your MySQL server timezone. What happens usually is your MySQL server might be set to UTC timezone hence time in database is considered as UTC, now as you have set Magento Timezone to Indian Standard Time, the time showed in Magento is +5:30 hrs of UTC.
So change your MySQL server timezone to IST.

Comment: Yes, it is UTC timezone.

Comment: In that case please change your MySQL timezone to IST.